# Regex for custom password requirements

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords, salesforce

I was trying to create a regex as per the password requirements.The requirement is

- Minimum eight (8) characters
- At least one number (0-9)
- Any three of the following:

  - Lowercase
  - Uppercase
  - Number
- Special character (   ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ )

I created this regex

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z\s!"#$\%&'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:;<=>?@\[\\\]\^\_\`\{\|\}\~]+$/g
```

I don't have that much knowledge of regex so just need confirmation is it right regex or need changes.

Comment: If I've read it correctly, your regex is `^[long list of alternatives]+$`. Well, in this case it will also match `hello`.

Comment: Complex password rules will usually not lead to more safe passwords, important is only a minimum length. People cannot remember tons of strong passwords, and such rules can interfere with good password schemes. People can get very inventive to bypass such rules, e.g. by using weak passwords like "Password-2020". Often you end up with weaker passwords instead of stronger ones. NIST published an [official paper](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html) advising against such rules, and against its former recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
^(?=.*\d)[ !"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~\w-]{8,}$
```

[image]

---

Code example

```js
const regex = /^(?=.*\d)[ !"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~\w-]{8,}$/gm;
const str = `1234
adnc
123456789
abcdefghij
ABCDEFGHIJ
1ABCDEFG
123-ANCNA
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

***PS:-*** I have replaced `\s` from pattern with , if you need to match all type of space character you can replace  with `\s` again

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.*?\d)(?=.*[\s!\"#$\%&'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:;<=>?@\[\\\]\^\_\`\{\|\}\~])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9].*?[a-zA-Z0-9].*?[a-zA-Z0-9].*?).*$
```

As seen **[here at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/we5EAG/2)**

## Explanation:

I've used a lot of positive lookaheads, which you can read more about [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Basically, a forward lookahead ensures that some position has some characters in front of it. After checking if the start of the password is followed by all your conditions, we then match the password.
Think of it like this: You make sure everything is correct, and if it is, then you match the password. Otherwise you don't.

`(?=.{8,})` checks if there are at least 8 characters
`(?=.*?\d)` checks if there is at least 1 digit
`` ^(?=.{8,})(?=.*?\d)(?=.*[\s!\"#$\%&'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:;<=>?@\[\\\]\^\_\`\{\|\}\~]) `` checks if there are at least 3 letters and/or numbers